# Select row with max date from duplicate results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

Note: I am working with SQL 2000.

I would like to select the row with the MAX date for t2.JobCompletionTime by doing something like this for this Join but I know this is not the correct code/syntax as it does not work...but I hope it is clear what I am trying to do.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM DSM_StandardProcedureActivityView
  WHERE
  ( (PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 10'  AND PackageVersion = '-1.0') AND
    (MAX (JobCompletionTime))
  )
) t2 ON t1.UUID = t2.UUID
```

My full working SQL code as it stands now is:

```
SELECT 
t1.Business,
t1.[Sub-Business],
t1.Pole,
t1.DomainManager,
t1.ScalabilityServer,
t1.Location,
t1.Country,
t1.Name,
t3.VolumeName,
t3.VolumeFreeInMB,
t3.VolumeSizeInMB,
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM DSM_StandardGroupMembersView
  WHERE 
  (  GroupName = 'Adobe Acrobat'
  )
) t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM DSM_StandardProcedureActivityView
  WHERE
  ( (PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 10'  AND PackageVersion = '-1.0')
  )
) t2 ON t1.UUID = t2.UUID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM DSM_StandardHardwareDiskUsageView
  WHERE VolumeName = 'C:\'
) t3 ON t1.Name = t3.Name
ORDER BY t1.Business, t1.[Sub-Business], t1.Pole, t1.DomainManager, t1.ScalabilityServer, t1.Country, t1.Location, [Job Status], t1.Name
```

Comment: Personally I'd think about adding a couple of tables to hold your `Job Status` and `Error Description` descriptions. Also I'd not use sub-queries when referencing your main table and joined tables, and just make the WHERE clause for each, part of the main queries WHERE clause. This would make for a much more readable query.

Comment: It's not clear from your question what you're after. Could you elaborate on the statement: "*I am setting t2.JobCompletionTime as NULL if following is true, but I would still like to select the MAX t2.JobCompletionTime...*".

Comment: I edited the question above to hopefully provide more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going through this in steps as to make it more obvious where I might make an interpretation error here...

Step 1 : beautifying your query a bit + leaving out the `ORDER BY` as you can add that one easily later on again

```
SELECT t1.Business,
       t1.[Sub-Business],
       t1.Pole,
       t1.DomainManager,
       t1.ScalabilityServer,
       t1.Location,
       t1.Country,
       t1.Name,
       t3.VolumeName,
       t3.VolumeFreeInMB,
       t3.VolumeSizeInMB

  FROM DSM_StandardGroupMembersView  t1

  LEFT OUTER JOIN DSM_StandardProcedureActivityView t2
               ON t2.PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 10'  
              AND t2.PackageVersion = '-1.0'
              AND t2.UUID = t1.UUID

  LEFT OUTER JOIN DSM_StandardHardwareDiskUsageView t3
               ON t3.VolumeName = 'C:'
              AND t3.Name = t1.Name

 WHERE t1.GroupName = 'Adobe Acrobat'
```

The way I understand your question is that you you want to limit the records from DSM_StandardProcedureActivityView t2 to just those that represent the latest situation (based on the t2.JobCompletionTime field). Right ? Now either we go grouping this upfront and then join with those that match (by UUID), or we think of this the other way around and first let the list be limited to the needed UUID's and then strip out all those that 
have a more recent version.
Since you're on SQL2000 I'd suggest the latter as I'm not sure the Query Optimizer would be able to optimize the former. (feel free to test =)

This would then look something like this :

```
SELECT t1.Business,
       t1.[Sub-Business],
       t1.Pole,
       t1.DomainManager,
       t1.ScalabilityServer,
       t1.Location,
       t1.Country,
       t1.Name,
       t3.VolumeName,
       t3.VolumeFreeInMB,
       t3.VolumeSizeInMB

  FROM DSM_StandardGroupMembersView  t1

  LEFT OUTER JOIN DSM_StandardProcedureActivityView t2
               ON t2.PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 10'  
              AND t2.PackageVersion = '-1.0'
              AND t2.UUID = t1.UUID
              -- limit to latest records only!
              AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                                 FROM DSM_StandardProcedureActivityView t2_newer
                                WHERE t2_newer.UUID = t2.UUID
                                  AND t2_newer.JobCompletionTime > t2.JobCompletionTime )

  LEFT OUTER JOIN DSM_StandardHardwareDiskUsageView t3
               ON t3.VolumeName = 'C:'
              AND t3.Name = t1.Name

 WHERE t1.GroupName = 'Adobe Acrobat'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: PS: I've changed the `t3.VolumeName = 'C:\'` into `...= 'C:'` as it seemed to confuse the syntax-highlighter, you'll probably need to change it back to what it was when trying it out!

Answer (score 1):

You've posted too much irrelevant SQL for me to wade through, so I'll just fix your excerpt:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM DSM_StandardProcedureActivityView
    WHERE PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 10'
    AND PackageVersion = '-1.0'
    ORDER BY JobCompletionTime DESC) x
   ) y
   GROUP BY PackageName, PackageVersion
) t2 ON t1.UUID = t2.UUID
```

What's happening here is the inner query gets the rows sorted by lastest JobCompletionTime first, the next level query uses a group by on the matching columns, which in mysql, gives you the *first* matching row (the latest, since we sorted the rows)

Comment: I get an error when I run this code: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries, unless TOP is also specified.

Comment: I changed it to:
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT * 
      FROM (
             SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT *
             FROM DSM_StandardProcedureActivityView

But now I get an error that says:
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.
Incorrect syntax near 't3'.

Comment: Oh sorry - I could have sworn I saw a mysql tag. This will only work with mysql :(

Answer (score 1):

A ranking function called ROW_NUMBER() could help you here

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        rowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY JobCompletionTime DESC)
    FROM DSM_StandardProcedureActivityView
    WHERE PackageName = 'Adobe Acrobat 10'
    AND PackageVersion = '-1.0'
) t2 ON t1.UUID = t2.UUID AND rowNumber = 1
```

Ordering by the JobCompletionTime (descending) should put the highest value as row number 1; hence the extra clause added to the join clause.

Comment: Thank you for this solution but I am working with SQL 2000 and ROW_NUMBER() is a function added with SQL 2005 onwards.

Comment: My bad; I didn't see the sql-server-2000 tag. I'll leave the answer incase this is useful for others who are able to use ROW_NUMBER().